# Webix closing modalbox before get form data

Tags: javascript, webix

I'm using Webix modalbox.
I need to receive data from form included into this modalbox, but its dissapear before i get data.
Here's code:

`this.modalOpen = function (modal, form) {
    webix.message.keyboard = false;
    _Reference.$modal = webix.modalbox({
        view: "window",
        position: "center",
        title: modal.title,
        text: form,
        width: modal.width,
        buttons: modal.buttons,
        callback: function (result) {
            if(result === 0) {
                return false;
            }
            var functionName = modal.actions[result];
            if (typeof functionName === "function") {
                functionName.apply(null);
            }
        }
    });
 };`

And data included into this function is like

`this.route = "/detail/";
this.modalSettings = {
    create: {
        title: "Новая деталь",
        width: 500,
        buttons: ["ДОБАВИТЬ", "ОТМЕНА"],
        actions: [this.store, this.modalClose]
    },
    show: {
        title: ""
    },
    edit: {}
};`

Answer (score 0):

You can store reference for the modalbox, and read result after closing modalbox like next

```
var modal = {
  title: "Новая деталь",
  width: 500,
  buttons: ["ДОБАВИТЬ", "ОТМЕНА"],
  actions: [this.store, this.modalClose]
};

webix.message.keyboard = false;
var t = webix.modalbox({
  view: "window",
  position: "center",
  title: modal.title,
  text: "<input id='m1' type='text'>",
  width: modal.width,
  buttons: modal.buttons,
  callback: function (result) {
    if(result === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    var value = t.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    webix.message("value: "+value);
  }
});
```